# Opening an ACAD dwg file in opened ACAD application with vba

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

I have an excel file with part numbers listed in a column. On running, the code splits the first part number typed. From the first half the code finds the subfolder that contains that category of part numbers then the second half is the actual file name. Example `01T-1001-01`. 01T is the subfolder name and the `1001-01` is the file name, it splits at `-`. However sometimes descriptions of the part are added in parenthesis so for example `1001-01 (Chuck)`. That is what the wild card is for.

The code is supposed to first check if AutoCAD is opened, if so then open the dwg in the opened AutoCAD application, if not then open a new application.

The issue is that it will open one drawing (first in the list) but will error out with "Run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" It will not continue past `Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open(ACADPath)` to open the other dwgs in the list

**UPDATED Code below:**

```
Dim ACADApp As AcadApplication
Dim ACADPath As String
Dim ACAD As Object
Dim NFile As Object
Sub Open_Dwg()

Dim Wildcard As String
Dim path As String
Dim target As String
Dim SplitString() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer

i = 1

If ACAD Is Nothing Then
    Set ACAD = CreateObject("AutoCad.Application")

    If ACAD Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not start AutoCAD.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Else
        Set ACAD = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")
End If

Set ACADApp = ACAD
ACADApp.Visible = True

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
ACADPath = ""
Wildcard = ""
OpenString = ""

path = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\DEMO" 'Root Folder
target = Cells(i, 1).Value 'Get Targeted Cell Value
target = UCase(target) 'All Letters to Upper Case
SplitString() = Split(target, "-", 2) 'Split given name to obtain subfolder and name
path = path & "\" & SplitString(0) & "\" 'Build Complete Path

OpenString = path & SplitString(1) & ".dwg" 'File Path and Name
Wildcard = Dir(path & SplitString(1) & "*.dwg") 'File Path and Wildcard

If Dir(OpenString) <> "" Then
        ACADPath = OpenString
        OpenFile (ACADPath)
    Else
            If Wildcard <> "" Then 'If Not Then Use Wildcard
                ACADPath = path & Wildcard
                OpenFile (ACADPath)
            Else
                MsgBox ("File " & target & " Not Found")
            End If
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub

Function OpenFile(ByVal ACADPath As String) As String
    Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open(ACADPath)
End Function
```

Comment: Isn't the open command in Autocad like this? `Application.Documents.Open sFilename`

Comment: idk, let me try.... Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic shell of what I use in our production application:

```
Sub Open_Dwg()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim ACADApp As AcadApplication
   Dim a As Object

   Set a = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

   If a Is Nothing Then
      Set a = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")

      If a Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "AutoCAD must be running before performing this action.", vbCritical
         Exit Sub
      End If
   End If

   Set ACADApp = a
   ACADApp.Visible = True
   Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open("<your filename>")
End Sub
```

Note the modification of the GetObject call and how the document is being opened.

**EDIT:**

Using the above code as a starting point and applying it to the OP's code, you would end up with the following:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ACADApp As AcadApplication
Dim ACADPath As String
Dim ACAD As Object
Dim NFile As Object

Sub Open_Dwg()
   Dim Wildcard As String
   Dim OpenString As String
   Dim path As String
   Dim target As String
   Dim SplitString() As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim a As Integer

   'get or create an instance of autocad
   On Error Resume Next
   Set ACAD = Nothing
   Set ACAD = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

   If ACAD Is Nothing Then
      Set ACAD = CreateObject("AutoCad.Application")

      If ACAD Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Could not start AutoCAD.", vbCritical
         Exit Sub
      End If
   End If

   Set ACADApp = ACAD
   ACADApp.Visible = True
   On Error GoTo 0

   'process files
   i = 1

   Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
      path = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\DEMO" 'Root Folder
      target = UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) 'Get Targeted Cell Value
      SplitString() = Split(target, "-", 2) 'Split given name to obtain subfolder and name
      path = path & "\" & SplitString(0) & "\" 'Build Complete Path
      OpenString = path & SplitString(1) & ".dwg" 'File Path and Name
      Wildcard = Dir(path & SplitString(1) & "*.dwg") 'File Path and Wildcard

      If Dir(OpenString) <> "" Then
         OpenFile OpenString
      Else
         If Wildcard <> "" Then 'If Not Then Use Wildcard
            OpenFile path & Wildcard
         Else
            MsgBox ("File " & target & " Not Found")
         End If
      End If

      i = i + 1
   Loop
End Sub

Function OpenFile(ByVal ACADPath As String) As String
    ACADApp.Documents.Open ACADPath
End Function
```

Comment: doesn't like `Set ACAD = GetObject(, "ACAD.Application")` I get the error ActiveX component cant create object

Comment: If I move the `Set ACAD = GetObject(, "ACAD.Application")` into the If statement after `else` then I get "Invalid file name". Im using the file path plus the file name &.dwq in ``Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open("<your filename>")``

Comment: Your ProgID of "ACAD.Application" is not correct.  It should be "AutoCAD.Application".

Comment: Ok, I had an extra "\" in the path. Works!

Comment: So it works and opens the drawing, however it errors out with "Object doesn't support this property or method" But it does open the file. It stops the other dwgs from opening in the loop

Comment: `Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open("<your filename>")`

Comment: That line of code should work fine.  Perhaps you could add to your original post the updated code so we can investigate further?

Comment: Change Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open("<your filename>") to ACADApp.Documents.Open "<your filename>".  In other words, don't set the ActiveDocument.

Comment: It works now. I had `Set ACADApp.Document = ACADApp.Documents.Open(ACADPath)` and changed it to ``ACADApp.Documents.Open ACADPath`` I didn't see that you got rid of the ```Set``` Thank you